# Hotkey Keyboard Shortcut to focus / put cursor on Debug Console in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

What's the keyboard shortcut / hotkey combination for sending cursor focus to the Debug Console in Visual Studio Code?

(This is for working on a web / HTML / Javascript / Vue project.)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, there is no default hotkey.

#### Add Hotkey for Console

To add a keyboard shortcut for Debug Console focus go to:

File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > search for `console`

Double click on `Debug: Focus on Debug Console View`

Add the keyboard shortcut of your choice, e.g. Ctrl + Alt + C

[image: focus on debug console keyboard shortcut setting]

#### Return Focus to Editor Window

`Ctrl + 1` (the number one) will return cursor focus back to the last location/viewed file in the Editor window.