# How to keep cursor in debug console when debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the VS Code debugger to debug some C++ code. The problem is, every time I use "continue," "next," etc. to advance the code, my cursor exits the debug console and I can not type commands like "print" or "bt" without using the mouse to click back in the debug console. The same problem happens if I use the shortcuts F5, F10, etc. to debug. This is very time consuming and I am looking for a better way to debug, more like gdb in the Linux terminal.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497595/1981088.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code has a setting that toggles if the focus should switch to the editor on every break:

```json
"debug.focusEditorOnBreak": false
```